# Access Not Configured for Google OAUTH Login

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I am building a wordpress woocommerce site and am trying to get the users to login using G+.

Everything was going just fine till I changed the plugin I was using and added new redirect URLs to the OAUTH 2.0 Client ID.

Now the users get the error:

> Access Not Configured. Google+ API has not been used in project
>   1033299751186 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting
>   https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/plus/overview?project=1033299751186
>   then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for
>   the action to propagate to our systems and retry. Please notify about
>   this error to the Site Admin.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to google developer console as it says under the project 1033299751186 and enable the Google+ api.

Your project needs to have each of the different APIs enabled that it needs to access.

Look for API manager -> Enable APIs (its a tab at the top)

Comment: Thanks . Worked perfectly.